# Error while deploying Java AWS S3 code to openfaas

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, openfaas

Following is a part of code I have written:

```
S3Object obj1 = null; obj1 = s3client.getObject("bucketname", "file.yml"); 
S3ObjectInputStream instream = obj1.getObjectContent ();
```

I get the following error while deploying my code to openfaas:

> error: incompatible types: InputStream cannot be converted to
>   S3ObjectInputStream   S3ObjectInputStream instream =
>   obj1.getObjectContent ();

Comment: Can you add a little more context about what you are trying to do? A code snippet?

Comment: have you read the error message? It's pretty straightforward

Comment: S3Object obj1 = null;
 obj1 = s3client.getObject("bucketname", "file.yml");
 S3ObjectInputStream instream = obj1.getObjectContent ();
 @Yash

Comment: That is a compilation error.  It is highly unlikely that you are getting while **deploying** your code.

Comment: I have made the snippet provided by you as part of the problem. But as @Stephen C pointed out, you are highly unlikely to run into this problem only while deploying. Can you confirm if you are able to run this locally?

Comment: yes it is a compilation error.

Answer (score 0):

So I don't know a lot about AWS (yet), but reading the specification for the [S3Client](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/s3/S3Client.html), your declaration is possibly incorrect, as there does not seem to be an implementation of `S3Client.getObject()` that supports two `String` inputs. Instead it's looking for a `GetObjectRequest` (namely `S3Client.getObject(GetObjectRequest getObjectRequest)`)

So your implementation may have to be something as follows:

`S3Object s3Object = s3client.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(bucket, key))`

Here's an example : [Amazon.S3.Model.GetObjectRequest](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/S3/MS3GetObjectGetObjectRequest.html)

Comment: Tried that but still get the same error while compiling